# How to arrange a double array from biggest to smallest in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, double

```
var options = [Double(number1 / 1000), Double(number2 / 1000),Double(number3 / 1000),Double(number4 / 1000)];
```

I have the following code, and number1 to 4 are random numbers. How do I arrange the array such that the first element is the biggest element?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The absolute shortest way:

```
var array = [0.0034050000, 0.3483829244, 3.94339944]
array.sort(>)
```

Comment: In new version of Swift the function is called `sortInPlace()`, e.g. `array.sortInPlace(>)`.

Comment: It is now with Swift 4: array.sort(by: >)

Answer (score 6):

You can use custom comparison `{$0 > $1}` to sort your numbers in descending order:

```
let number1=10.0, number2 = 20.0, number3 = 30.0, number4 = 40.0
var options = [Double(number1 / 1000), Double(number2 / 1000),Double(number3 / 1000),Double(number4 / 1000)]
options.sort({$0 > $1})
println(options)
```